# How to load the zshrc file in Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter, zshrc

I would like to use an `py` alias for `python3` in my Jupyter notebook. Therefore, added `alias python=python3` in my zshrc file which works fine in the regular shell.

But if I would like to use it in Jupyter, for example like

```
!py --version
```

it doesn't work and return

```
zsh:1: command not found: py
```

How can I load zshrc file in Jupyter?